# Making a data-bind:click work like a marker.addListener()

Tags: javascript, google-maps, knockout.js

I'm making an app that uses knockoutjs to load google maps and multiple markers from an observableArray. There are corresponding `<li>` elements for each marker also pulled from my observableArray. Each marker has a `marker.addListener('click', function)` that pulls up an infowindow which will eventually have some info about that location in  pulled from an outside api. My issue is connecting the `<li>` elements with its corresponding marker. I would like to use a `data-bind='click:'` on a `<li>` element and have the same result as if I had clicked on the marker.

http://codepen.io/ntibbs/pen/ZbPPBm

I've tried doing something like

```
      this.marker.addListener('click', myFunction);

      this.zoom = function(){
        myFunction;
      }.bind(this);

        function myFunction() {
        if (infowindow) {
          infowindow.close();
        };
        contentString = '<div">'+
          this.title + '</div>';
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString,
          pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(50, 0),
        });  
        map.setZoom(9);
        map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
        infowindow.open(map, this);
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
          map.setZoom(7);
          map.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
        });
      };
```

But it is not working as I had hoped. Any insight on what I need to do differently or whats going wrong with my code would be a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing in your viewmodel is the collection of city information. That's more of a data model than a view model. In particular, the `zoom` function for your click binding isn't in your view model. It looks like it's part of the binding handler, and you're using `this` a lot in there, which is confusing to me.

To get your two types of clicks to do the same thing you really need to have `myFunction` available to the viewmodel and have the li-span click call it with the same data (or `this`) as the marker listeners do. This probably means making your custom binding handler take an object with several things in it (like callback for clicks).

You might find [this binding for maps](https://github.com/manuel-guilbault/knockout.google.maps) helpful. He gives a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manuel_guilbault/LBf8G/).